How to handle request.body is null which is send by client in node.js express?
If client purpose send post request with request body is null, how to handle this in node.js expresss. Please see the /api/health-check. Request is post but request body is null. I got the error
SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'n', "null" is not valid JSON
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/Users/aungmyooo/Development/INTERVIEW-TEST/teamups-tech-x/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:169:10)
    at parse (/Users/aungmyooo/Development/INTERVIEW-TEST/teamups-tech-x/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:86:15)
    at /Users/aungmyooo/Development/INTERVIEW-TEST/teamups-tech-x/server/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:128:18
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:206:9)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/aungmyooo/Development/INTERVIEW-TEST/teamups-tech-x/server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:238:16)
    at done (/Users/aungmyooo/Development/INTERVIEW-TEST/teamups-tech-x/server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:227:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/Users/aungmyooo/Development/INTERVIEW-TEST/teamups-tech-x/server/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:287:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:518:28)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:domain:488:12)

express app
import express, { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";
import cors from "cors"; // Import the cors middleware
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

import coustomerLoyaltyRouter from "./routes/customer-loyalty-route";

require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();

// Enable CORS for only localhost:3000
app.use(cors({
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/api", coustomerLoyaltyRouter);

// Define a route for the health check endpoint
app.post("/api/health-check", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  if (!req.body) {
    // Check if request body is null or empty
    res.status(400).json({ error: "Request payload is null or empty" });
    return;
  }

  res.json({ message: "pong" });
});

app.use((err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).json({ error: err });
});

export default app;


Does this answer your question? Catch express bodyParser error

the error you show arises from sending not null but string "null" as JSON, which is not valid, hence the error... sending proper null should trigger route middleware !req.body block, instead of body parser error

@traynor Yes, client request paylaod is purposely pass null . If payload is {}, I can check.

in that case, I'd consider it a malformed request, which should be handled on server level, like suggested in the linked post, or in more details here Error Handling

The issue is with body parser you pass options { strict: false } to allow null and other primitive values to be parsed
app.use(bodyParser.json({ strict: false }));

